Laravel - Query being run twice
I'm making a wedding planning application where users can add their guests to certain tables, groups, etc...
I'm trying to list all the groups and inside each group show every guest on that group(in the same page like and accordion)
Seems easy enough, and it works but while using DebugBar I can see it's making 2 queries that are exactly the same and I can't for the life of me find out why.
An Event can have many groups and each group can have many guests.
$event = Event::find($id_event);
$event->load('group');
$event->group->load([
    "guest" => function ($q) {
       return $q->paginate(10);
    }
]);

The result:

Edit
Forgot to mention, if I add any other relations to this it's will also duplicate them.
$event->group->load([
    'guest.plusone',
    "guest" => function ($q) {
       $q->paginate(10);
    }
]);


Edit 2
In trying to do what you suggested I found what causes it, but still don't know why.
When I try to do what you suggested I get the same outcome
$event->load(['group', 'group.guest' => function ($query) {
    $query->paginate(10);
}]);

But if I remove the callback for the pagination I only get one query.
Is this normal? I know pagination does one extra query to get the total results but in this case it's making 3 queries and 2 of them are exactly the same

first of all please try to name your relations by their type, example if event has many groups name the relation "groups" not "group", same for guests. Secondly can you try $event->load('group.guest'); and see what queries run. As well as not calling load at all, what queries run in that case?

@krisgjika In reality this application is already complete, but was made by one of our interns so it has multiple problems performance wise. I'm afraid of changing this relations as they can create more problems.
As for your recommendation you can see the edit above

perhaps you are mistaking limit with paginate? why would you paginate the relationship models?

also make sure you are on Laravel 11 when using limits on inner relations queries, as the result might not be what you expect

We need paginate because you can have unlimited groups, if we list 100 groups and each has 100 guests, there would be  1000+ guests loaded. We used paginate to not do pagination by hand. But I just tested with limit and it works fine.

I tried upgrading to laravel 11 but it's as simple, we need to redo the whole cashier stripe integration. I think I'll opt to make the pagination by hand

First of all for what you are doing, the result of 2 queries is very expected. See below for the explanation:
Explanation:
$event = Event::query()->find($id_event);
$event->load(['group.guest' => fn ($with) $with->paginate(10)]);

when calling paginate you are forcing a query to be run, the same query that has been built by the relation definitions up to that point. The same would happen calling $with->get(). But the closure does not expect you to run a query, nor does it care for that matter, only modify the query provided within. So after a query runs via paginate, note that it's result is not used anywhere, the closure ends and Laravel runs the relationship eager loading query as it normally would.
For Laravel 11:
for what you want to achive, limit the loaded relation models to 10 per group, you need to use a limit. Limit does not run a query, but modifies the query object to include a limit when it runs.
$event = Event::query()->find($id_event);
$event->load(['group.guest' => fn ($with) $with->limit(10)]);

Before Laravel 11:
while you can do the same in Laravel 10, the result you will get is not the same. The limit will apply to the whole loaded guests, not per group. So if you have group A and B with 10 guests each. The resulting data would include the 10 guests of group A but 0 guests on group B. This is because only 10 guests where loaded in total, not 10 for each group.
$event = Event::query()->find($id_event);
$event->load(['group.guest' => fn ($with) $with->limit(10)]);

To achieve the same functionality you need to include https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit into your project and follow it's instructions. (In Laravel 11 this package has been merged)
